# How can I inject plugins functionalities to the Vuex store using Nuxt without Typescript error?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I'm working in a Nuxtjs app with typescript and I've created a custom plugin for Axios that injects some functions to the context. I can use those functions from the store (it works) but, even though I got an error that tells me that the property that I'm using does not exist in the type store. What is the right way to do this? is there any configuration that must be done?

**This is the code of the plugin axios.js**

```
export default function ({ $axios, redirect }, inject) {

  $axios.onResponse((response) => {
    if (response.data == null)
      console.log(`Undefined or null data from url ${response.config.url}`)
  })

  $axios.onError((error) => {
    const code = parseInt(error.response && error.response.status)
    console.log('REQUEST ERROR')
    console.log('ENDPOINT:',error.request?.responseURL);
    
    if(error.response)
      console.log(error.response.data)
    else
      console.log("SIN DATOS")
    if (code === 404) {
      redirect('/404')
    }
  })

  const request = async (
    method = 'get',
    path,
    data = {},  
    params = {}
  ) => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      method: method,
      url: $axios.defaults.baseURL + path,
      data: data,
      params: params
    }

    return $axios(config)
  }

  const get = (path,params) => request(undefined,path,undefined,params)
  const post = (path, data) => request('post',path,data)

  const customAxios = {
      get,
      post
  }

  // Inject to context as $customAxios
  inject('customAxios', customAxios)
}
```

**This is a fraction of a code where I use the plugin, user.ts**

```
//ACTIONS
export const actions: ActionTree<RootState, RootState> = {
  setPhoneLink({ commit }, setPhoneLink: string) {
    commit('setPhoneLink', setPhoneLink)
  },
  setHasSameAddressOfId({ commit }, sethasSameAddressOfId: boolean) {
    commit('setHasSameAddressOfId', sethasSameAddressOfId)
  },
  async login({ commit }, loginBody: LoginBody) {
    return this.$customAxios
      .post('seguridad/login/web/', loginBody)
      .then((response: any) => {
        console.log('RESPONSE OF LOGIN:', response.data)
        commit('setUserData', response.data)
      })
  },
```

**This is the error I get**

```
ERROR in store/user.ts:229:17
TS2339: Property '$customAxios' does not exist on type 'Store<any>'.
    227 |   },
    228 |   async login({ commit }, loginBody: LoginBody) {
  > 229 |     return this.$customAxios
        |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    230 |       .post('seguridad/login/web/', loginBody)
    231 |       .then((response: any) => {
    232 |         console.log('RESPONSE OF LOGIN:', response.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Store<S>` is a defined type in Vuex, so you need to extend it by injecting your custom plugin inside.

You can create `vuex.d.ts` file that declares `Store<S>` with your custom axios instance as below:

```
import type { NuxtAxiosInstance } from '@nuxtjs/axios'

declare module 'vuex/types/index' {
  interface Store<S> {
    $customAxios: NuxtAxiosInstance
  }
}
```